# CakePHP login by Username Or Email using Auth component

Tags: cakephp

In my present system I need to login using username or email and password.
can anybody knows how to achieve this ?

My Form:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
  echo $this->Form->input('username', array('class' => 'TextField js-user-mode'));
 echo $this->Form->input('password', array('class' => 'TextField')); 
?>
```

MY AppController:

```
public $components = array(


        'Email'=>array(),
        'Auth'              => array(
            'loginAction'       => array(
                'admin'             => false,
                'controller'        => 'users',
                'action'            => 'login'
            ),
            'authError'     => 'Your session has ended due to inactivity.  Please login to continue.',
            'authenticate'  => array(
                'Form'          => array(
                    'fields'        => array('username' => array('username','email')),
                ),
                'all' => array(
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                    'scope' => array('User.status' =>array('active'))
                )

            )
        )
    );
```

Let me know what else i need to do..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply we can do this before your Auth login action:

```
$emailUsername = @$this->request->data['User']['email'];
if (!filter_var($emailUsername, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { 
    $emailFromUsername = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $emailUsername), 'recursive' => -1, 'fields' => array('email')));
    //pr($emailFromUsername );
    if (!empty($emailFromUsername)) {
        $emailFromUsernameDB = $emailFromUsername['User']['email'];
    } else {
        $emailFromUsername = '';
    }
    $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $emailFromUsername;
}
```

Comment: This is also useful for when you have the emails, but dont have the username.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure what the etiquette is on posting answers to old questions but here's what I did for this.

In my login function

```
        $username  = $this->data['User']['username'];
        $password = $this->request->data['User']['password'];

        $user = $this->User->findByUsername($username);
        if (empty($user)) {
            $user = $this->User->findByEmail($username);

            if (empty($user)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect Email/Username or Password'));
                return;
            }
            $this->request->data['User']['username'] = $user['User']['username'];
        }
```

Comment: You're more than welcome to answer old questions. Even if the asker might not need help anymore, you'll be helping future visitors.

Answer (score 4):

I found following code from this [url](https://gist.github.com/fitorec/3008900). I think this is the best in sense of simplicity. Use following code on your **login** action:

```
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')&&!empty($this->request->data)) {
        App::Import('Utility', 'Validation');
        if( isset($this->data['User']['username']) && Validation::email($this->request->data['User']['username'])) {
            $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
            $this->Auth->authenticate['Form'] = array('fields' => array('username' => 'email'));
        }
        if($this->Auth->login()) {
            /* login successful */
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            /* login unsuccessful */
        }
    }
}
```

And also use following code for **login.ctp** :

```
<?php
    echo $this->form->create('User');
    echo $this->form->input('username');
    echo $this->form->input('password');
    echo $this->form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Comment: May look like a hack but it is a "near-correct" answer unless they have a more "elegant" way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the MultipleColumn Auth adapter:

https://github.com/ceeram/Authenticate/blob/master/Controller/Component/Auth/MultiColumnAuthenticate.php

Update:
New version @ https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/blob/master/src/Auth/MultiColumnAuthenticate.php

Comment: Can you please tell me how to use it, do i need to modify my authcomponent

Comment: Its all documented? Both in the class and the readme? https://github.com/ceeram/Authenticate#configuration

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming you have **username** and **email** both fields in your users table

In your AppController.php

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if ($this->request->is('post') && $this->action == 'login') {
        $username = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
        if (filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $this->Auth->authenticate['Form']['fields']['username'] = 'email';
            $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $username;
            unset($this->request->data['User']['username']);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will work for CakePHP 2.x, not tested on version 3.x, you should have email field in your user's table.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution useful.
I have created two classes that extend FormAuthenticate:

**app/Controller/Component/Auth/ClassNameAuthenticate.php** and

```
<?php
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class ClassNameAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate {
}
```

**app/Controller/Component/Auth/ClassNameEmailAuthenticate.php**

```
<?php
App::uses('FormAuthenticate', 'Controller/Component/Auth');

class ClassNameEmailAuthenticate extends FormAuthenticate {
}
```

then in my Controller added Auth Component to $components

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'ClassName' =>array(
                'userModel'=>'ClassName',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                ),
                'scope' => array('ClassName.active' => 1)
            ),
            'ClassNameEmail' =>array(
                'userModel'=>'ClassName',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'email',
                ),
                'scope' => array('ClassName.active' => 1)
            )                
        )
    ),
);
```

**login view: login.ctp**

```
<div class="form">
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('ClassName'); ?>
    <fieldset>
      <legend><?php echo __('Login'); ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('username');
            echo $this->Form->input('password');
        ?>
    </fieldset>

  <?php echo $this->Form->end(array('label'=>__('Login'))); ?>
</div>
```

and login() action:

```
 public function login(){

    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
    }

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        //Need to duplicate field email for ClassNameEmail Auth
        $this->request->data['ClassName']['email'] = $this->request->data['ClassName']['username'];

        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } 

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username/email or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

I hope someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution to solve that problem

```
public function login(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->User->set($this->request->data);
        if($this->User->validates()){
            if(Validation::email($this->data['User']['username'])){
                $this->Auth->authenticate['Form'] = array_merge($this->Auth->authenticate['Form'],array('fields'=>array('username'=>'email')));
                $this->request->data['User']['email'] = $this->request->data['User']['username'];
                unset($this->request->data['User']['username']);
            }
            if($this->Auth->login()){
                $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
                $this->User->saveField('last_login',time());
                if($this->data['User']['remember']){
                    unset($this->request->data['User']['remember']);
                    $this->request->data['User']['password'] = Security::hash($this->request->data['User']['password'],'blowfish');
                    $this->Cookie->write('rememberMe',$this->request->data['User'],true,'2 days');
                }
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->loginRedirect);
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Username or Password entered, please try again.','default',array('class'=>'alert alert-warning'),'warning');
        }
    }
    $this->set('title','Login Page');
}
```