# CakePHP 3 - Multiple field Auth login

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to login using multiple field checking.

**Current situation :** Using (`Email`) And (`Password`) fields for login

```html
<div>
   <input name="email" placeholder="Email">
   <input name="password" placeholder="Password">
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
```

**Here is my AuthComponent configurations :**

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    #Some other configuration
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => ['username' => 'email']
        ]
    ],
    'storage' => 'Session'
 ]);
```

**My expectation :** Using (`Email` Or `Phone`) And (`Password`) fields for login

```html
<div>
   <input name="email_or_phone" placeholder="Email or Phone">
   <input name="password" placeholder="Password">
   <input type="submit" value="Login">
</div>
```

How can I configure ***AuthComponent*** to meet this situation?

Comment: Your inputs don't even have `name` attributes, ie the browser wouldn't submit any data. You should start with using the form helper for building forms.

Comment: Yes! I know. Thank you.  This is just for an example. I used `Form Helper`, But multiple field is not working for me. :( @ndm

Comment: I see, you should update the examples with your actual code then, as this will only confuse people and distract them from the actual problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to authenticate based on an "either or" basis, then you have to use a custom finder, as the built-in finder of the authenticator is designed to match against a single column only.

In your form define the input:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('email_or_phone'); ?>
```

In your auth configuration set up the fields and finder:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email_or_phone'
            ],
            'finder' => 'auth'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

In your (probably `UsersTable`) table class define the finder, where you can use the `username` option to build the required conditions:

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->where(
        [
            'OR' => [
                $this->aliasField('email') => $options['username'],
                $this->aliasField('phone') => $options['username'],
            ]
        ],
        [],
        true
    );
}
```

Note that the value that the authenticator grabs from the request via the configured `email_or_phone` field, will *always* be passed to the finder in the `username` option!

Also note that you have to either remove possible existing conditions generated by the authenticator, or overwrite them as show in this example, using the third argument of [**`Query::where()`**](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_where).

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Configuring Authentication Handlers](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > Authentication > Customizing Find Query](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)**

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. <3 <3

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
    #Some other configuration
    'authenticate' => [
        'Form' => [
            'fields' => ['username' => ['email','phone']]
        ]
    ],
    'storage' => 'Session'
 ]);
```

Just pass the values as array to `username`.

And in your login function do something like:

```
$username  = $this->data['User']['username'];
$user = $this->User->findByEmail($username);
if (empty($user))
{
    $user = $this->User->findByPhone($username);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I can also do it using Magic Method like `$this->{MODEL}->findByEmailOrPhone('{EMAIL}','{PHONE}')`. But actually i don't want to do like as this. I want this task handled from `AuthComponent`.

Comment: @SumonSarker OK, as I said you can pass values as array on the authComponent. you can access it however you want in the login function.

Comment: @SumonSarker If my solution helped than be sure to accept it.

Comment: Have you actually tested this @mega6382? I really doubt that you can use an array for the `username` option, this should already fail when the authenticator tries to read the request data.

Comment: @ndm I didn't test it myself, but I saw an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977959/cakephp-login-by-username-or-email-using-auth-component

Comment: That looks like CakePHP 2.x, but I'm pretty sure it doesn't work there either.